# Concurrent Access Issue during .NET Build in KB with GeneXus 18 Upgrade 5

Tags: asp.net, .net, genexus

I'm working with a Genexus KB 18 Upgrade5, generating for .NET.
It's a small KB (less than 1000 objects), and it uses GAM.

When I execute a 'build all', intermittently but **very frequently**, I encounter the following error:

```
    Success: Default (.NET) Generation
Compressing static files...Success
========== DeveloperMenu Compilation for Default (.NET) started ==========
dotnet build -nologo -c Debug /v:q /m /p:Configuration=Debug /p:GxExternalReference=GeneXus.Security.API.Common.dll "D:\KBs\GX18\MT18_v6\Pro\build\LastBuild.sln"
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.308\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2302,5): error MSB4018: The "ResolveAssemblyReference" task failed unexpectedly. [D:\KBs\GX18\MT18_v6\Pro\build\global.usuario.aexportreportwwusuario\global.usuario.aexportreportwwusuario.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.308\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2302,5): error MSB4018: System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'D:\KBs\GX18\MT18_v6\Pro\web\bin\Microsoft.Identity.Client.dll' because it is being used by another process. [D:\KBs\GX18\MT18_v6\Pro\build\global.usuario.aexportreportwwusuario\global.usuario.aexportreportwwusuario.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.308\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2302,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.CreateFile(String fullPath, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options) [D:\KBs\GX18\MT18_v6\Pro\build\global.usuario.aexportreportwwusuario\global.usuario.aexportreportwwusuario.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.308\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2302,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.Open(String fullPath, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize) [D:\KBs\GX18\MT18_v6\Pro\build\global.usuario.aexportreportwwusuario\global.usuario.aexportreportwwusuario.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.308\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2302,5): error MSB4018:    at System.IO.Strategies.OSFileStreamStrategy..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize) [D:\KBs\GX18\MT18_v6\Pro\build\global.usuario.aexportreportwwusuario\global.usuario.aexportreportwwusuario.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.308\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2302,5): error MSB4018:    at System.IO.File.OpenRead(String path) [D:\KBs\GX18\MT18_v6\Pro\build\global.usuario.aexportreportwwusuario\global.usuario.aexportreportwwusuario.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.308\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2302,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.Shared.AssemblyNameExtension.GetAssemblyNameEx(String path) [D:\KBs\GX18\MT18_v6\Pro\build\global.usuario.aexportreportwwusuario\global.usuario.aexportreportwwusuario.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.308\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2302,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ResolveAssemblyReference.<>c.<Execute>b__255_3(String p) [D:\KBs\GX18\MT18_v6\Pro\build\global.usuario.aexportreportwwusuario\global.usuario.aexportreportwwusuario.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.308\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2302,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.SystemState.GetAssemblyName(String path) [D:\KBs\GX18\MT18_v6\Pro\build\global.usuario.aexportreportwwusuario\global.usuario.aexportreportwwusuario.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.308\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2302,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Resolver.FileMatchesAssemblyName(AssemblyNameExtension assemblyName, Boolean isPrimaryProjectReference, Boolean wantSpecificVersion, Boolean allowMismatchBetweenFusionNameAndFileName, String pathToCandidateAssembly, ResolutionSearchLocation searchLocation) [D:\KBs\GX18\MT18_v6\Pro\build\global.usuario.aexportreportwwusuario\global.usuario.aexportreportwwusuario.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.308\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2302,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Resolver.ResolveAsFile(String fullPath, AssemblyNameExtension assemblyName, Boolean isPrimaryProjectReference, Boolean wantSpecificVersion, Boolean allowMismatchBetweenFusionNameAndFileName, List`1 assembliesConsideredAndRejected) [D:\KBs\GX18\MT18_v6\Pro\build\global.usuario.aexportreportwwusuario\global.usuario.aexportreportwwusuario.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.308\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2302,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Resolver.ResolveFromDirectory(AssemblyNameExtension assemblyName, Boolean isPrimaryProjectReference, Boolean wantSpecificVersion, String[] executableExtensions, String directory, List`1 assembliesConsideredAndRejected) [D:\KBs\GX18\MT18_v6\Pro\build\global.usuario.aexportreportwwusuario\global.usuario.aexportreportwwusuario.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.308\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2302,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.DirectoryResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameExtension assemblyName, String sdkName, String rawFileNameCandidate, Boolean isPrimaryProjectReference, Boolean wantSpecificVersion, String[] executableExtensions, String hintPath, String assemblyFolderKey, List`1 assembliesConsideredAndRejected, String& foundPath, Boolean& userRequestedSpecificFile) [D:\KBs\GX18\MT18_v6\Pro\build\global.usuario.aexportreportwwusuario\global.usuario.aexportreportwwusuario.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.308\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2302,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.AssemblyResolution.ResolveReference(IEnumerable`1 jaggedResolvers, AssemblyNameExtension assemblyName, String sdkName, String rawFileNameCandidate, Boolean isPrimaryProjectReference, Boolean wantSpecificVersion, String[] executableExtensions, String hintPath, String assemblyFolderKey, List`1 assembliesConsideredAndRejected, String& resolvedSearchPath, Boolean& userRequestedSpecificFile) [D:\KBs\GX18\MT18_v6\Pro\build\global.usuario.aexportreportwwusuario\global.usuario.aexportreportwwusuario.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.308\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2302,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ReferenceTable.ResolveReference(AssemblyNameExtension assemblyName, String rawFileNameCandidate, Reference reference) [D:\KBs\GX18\MT18_v6\Pro\build\global.usuario.aexportreportwwusuario\global.usuario.aexportreportwwusuario.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.308\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2302,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ReferenceTable.ResolveAssemblyFilenames() [D:\KBs\GX18\MT18_v6\Pro\build\global.usuario.aexportreportwwusuario\global.usuario.aexportreportwwusuario.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.308\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2302,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ReferenceTable.ComputeClosure() [D:\KBs\GX18\MT18_v6\Pro\build\global.usuario.aexportreportwwusuario\global.usuario.aexportreportwwusuario.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.308\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2302,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ReferenceTable.ComputeClosure(IEnumerable`1 remappedAssembliesValue, ITaskItem[] referenceAssemblyFiles, ITaskItem[] referenceAssemblyNames, List`1 exceptions) [D:\KBs\GX18\MT18_v6\Pro\build\global.usuario.aexportreportwwusuario\global.usuario.aexportreportwwusuario.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.308\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2302,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ResolveAssemblyReference.Execute(FileExists fileExists, DirectoryExists directoryExists, GetDirectories getDirectories, GetAssemblyName getAssemblyName, GetAssemblyMetadata getAssemblyMetadata, GetLastWriteTime getLastWriteTime, GetAssemblyRuntimeVersion getRuntimeVersion, GetAssemblyPathInGac getAssemblyPathInGac, IsWinMDFile isWinMDFile, ReadMachineTypeFromPEHeader readMachineTypeFromPEHeader) [D:\KBs\GX18\MT18_v6\Pro\build\global.usuario.aexportreportwwusuario\global.usuario.aexportreportwwusuario.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.308\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2302,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ResolveAssemblyReference.Execute() [D:\KBs\GX18\MT18_v6\Pro\build\global.usuario.aexportreportwwusuario\global.usuario.aexportreportwwusuario.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.308\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2302,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute() [D:\KBs\GX18\MT18_v6\Pro\build\global.usuario.aexportreportwwusuario\global.usuario.aexportreportwwusuario.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.308\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2302,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask(ITaskExecutionHost taskExecutionHost, TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext, TaskHost taskHost, ItemBucket bucket, TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask) [D:\KBs\GX18\MT18_v6\Pro\build\global.usuario.aexportreportwwusuario\global.usuario.aexportreportwwusuario.csproj]
Build FAILED.
```

The issues seem to arise with **Microsoft.Identity.Client.dll** and also with **BouncyCastle.Crypto.dll**.

Repeating the 'build all' operation sometimes resolves the error temporarily.

It feels like there's some concurrency issue with multiple dotnet tasks being run by Genexus. I'm struggling to find a way to work efficiently without these interruptions. Does anyone have insights on how to address this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try changing parallel compilation to serial using parameter /m:1
More information: [Concurrent Access Issue during .NET Build in KB with GeneXus 18 Upgrade 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77091121/concurrent-access-issue-during-net-build-in-kb-with-genexus-18-upgrade-5)